# Shell script to check ubuntu version and then copy files

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am new to shell script programming. I want to write a simple shell script to check the ubuntu version installed in the system; if the version is greater than or equal to version 12 then copy some files, and if it's less then copy some other files.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i had tried few basics scripting like copying files and executing few commands, but i didn't had much knowledge in condition checking in shell script

Comment: It's done as on every other programming language with an `if` statment. I'm sure a bit of searching could help you.

Answer (score 21):

The `lsb_release -rs` command lets us determine the Ubuntu version, we could use it like this:

```
if [[ $(lsb_release -rs) == "18.04" ]]; then # replace 8.04 by the number of release you want

       echo "Compatible version"
       #Copy your files here
else
       echo "Non-compatible version"
fi
```

`` (enclosing backticks) is non-POSIX and deprecated.

Comment: Using `lsb_release -rs` even omits the `Release:` part.

Comment: Indeed, this shortens the entire solution. I've edited the answer so that this sed-stuff is omitted. Thanks for pointing out, @A.H. !

Comment: This requires bash, so it won't work if using /bin/sh

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /etc/issue.net |  awk '{x=2 ; if (substr($x,0,3) == '12') {system("cp <src> <dest>") } else {system("cp <src> <dest>") }}'
```

`cat /etc/issue.net` will show 3 fields out of which 2nd field is version no.

by `substr` we check the first two digit if it is version 12 then by system command inside `awk` we can copy certain files from a particular src to dest.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: `cat /proc/version` , parse the number and perform condition/switch statement for performing an action.

From **RadHat** [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-proc-topfiles#s2-proc-version):

> This file specifies the version of the Linux kernel and gcc in use, as well as the version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux installed on the system: